# Elements of $F_q$ of the form $ax^2$

Tags: quadratic-forms

I'm reading Serre's A Course in Arithmetic and I can't understand the following statement in the proof of Ch. 4, 1.7 prop 4. It says

(here, $q=p^f$ is a power of a prime $p\neq 2$ and $F_q$ is a field with $q$ elements.)

Let $A$ (resp. $B$) be the set of elements of $F_q$ of the form $ax^2$(resp. of the form $c-by^2$) with $x \in F_q$ (resp. with $y\in F_q$). One sees easily that $A$ and $B$ each have $(q+1)/2$ elements.

I can easily see why this is true when $q=p$ but I'm so lost when $q=p^f$ for some $f>1$. For example, if we take $q=3^2$, then I can only find 4 elements of the from $x^2$, $(0,0), (0,1), (1,0)$ and $(1,1)$ - which makes sense to me since $F_q \cong Z_3\oplus Z_3$.

I bet I'm making a really dumb mistake but I spent more than 3 hours and still have no clue. Can anyone shine me some light please?

Comment: What is (0,1)*(1,0)? You can't take multiplication pointwise. I think it is better to use polynomials, so the elements are ta+s for a an indeterminate and t and s from the base field. Then it is easy to see that zero is its own square and the nonzero elements pair off under the square map.  Also, ask these questions on math.stack exchange please.  This forum handles different material.  Gerhard "Better Living Through Polynomial Forms" Paseman, 2017.04.11.

Comment: I agree with @GerhardPaseman, but the argument is that the multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic, and $x-> 2 x$ is a $2-1$ map for a cyclic group of even order. Throw in zero, and you are good to go.

Comment: Direct sums of fields are never fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake (I won't call it "dumb"—we all make mistakes—and this is a somewhat subtle point!) is that *as rings*, $\Bbb F_9$ is not isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_3\times\Bbb Z_3$. (Here, to be clear, $\Bbb Z_n$ is a shorthand for $\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z$.) Indeed, it's an even more common mistake to assert that $\Bbb F_9$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_9$, but that's also incorrect. For example, note that $\Bbb F_9$ has no zero-divisors (since it's a field). But $\Bbb Z_3\times\Bbb Z_3$ has four zero-divisors, namely $(0,1)$, $(0,2)$, $(1,0)$, and $(2,0)$. And $\Bbb Z_9$ has two zero-divisors, namely $3$ and $6$.

It is true that $\Bbb F_9$ is a vector space of dimension 2 over $\Bbb F_3$; in particular, $\Bbb F_9$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_3\times\Bbb Z_3$ *as additive groups*. But rings have multiplications as well; and if we think of $\Bbb Z_3\times\Bbb Z_3$ as a product ring with its component-wise multiplication, then that is not the same as the multiplication in $\Bbb F_9$. As Gerhard "Too Many Middle Names to Count" Paseman comments, representing $\Bbb F_9$ as $\Bbb F_3[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle$ for an irreducible quadratic polynomial $f(x)\in\Bbb F_3[x]$ is probably the best way to keep track of the multiplication.

(In general, the rings $\Bbb F_p \cong \Bbb Z_p$ when $p$ is a prime, but $\Bbb F_{p^m} \not\cong \Bbb Z_{p^m}$ when $m\ge2$; indeed, $\Bbb F_{p^m}$ and $\Bbb Z_{p^m}$ are not even isomorphic as additive groups.)